# Manipulating strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

**Disclosure:** This is university work. I am not expecting code to accomplish my task rather I want to understand how best to manipulate strings in C.

I need to write a function to manipulate a string in a certain way (I'm not saying what so as to ensure that no-one provides exact code).

In python I'd just do the following

```
def foo(str):
  return str
```

Clearly things aren't as easy as that in C.

Can anyone tell me how best to achieve this. Should I use pointers to simulate passing by reference and just manipulate the original string? Any help / resources would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: I do want to preform an operation on the string and return the result of that operation (also a string). I am happy to manipulate the original string or return it. Which ever would be considered best practice.

The task I've been set is based on how to do that operation so I didn't want to make that explicit.

So the Python would be:

```
def foo(str):
  #do something to str (which doesn't change it's length)
  return str
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. You say that you want to manipulate a string, but this question says that you want a function that returns whatever string is passed to it.

Comment: I know you mean to be vague, but that is too vague.

Comment: Have you read section 8 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to operate on the string and return that value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. If you manipulate the original string you don't need to return anything
2. If you don't want to change the original string you should copy it with `strdup` or `malloc + strcpy` and return a pointer (`char *`) to it. The caller of course must `free` it when done.

It all rests on the question: **will the caller need the original string** ?

Comment: Well, some nitpicking. The function cannot decide if the caller needs the original string. The function must explicitly declare what does it do: modifies the given memory or allocates some memory itself for the result. The caller must now think whether the original string is needed (if the callee is going to modify it), and (if needed) allocate a copy.

Comment: A little more nitpicking: the best you can do in C is declare what the function can do. But you absolutely SHOULD add documentation to indicate that the function does or does not modify data passed into it.

Comment: @ObscureRobot Rather than documentation a `const char *` as parameter will be preferable I think ?

Comment: The caller has no real need to retain original string. The task requires I modify the string.

Comment: @Prydie There you have it. `void change_my_str(char *str) { ... }`.

Comment: @cnicutar you are correct, though documenting intent is never a bad idea.

Comment: I'll come back to this tomorrow and try and figure it out. I'm still not sure I quite understand. I'll do some more reading.

Answer (score 1):

There are many conventions, but the most common one seems to be:

```
void foo(char *destination, const char *source);
```

or

```
void foo(char *destination, size_t dest_len, const char *source);
```

So you are passing the original string in `source` as `const` (it is not going to be modified by the function), and the output string is written in `destination`.

Of course, the caller needs to make sure that `destination` is of a sufficient size, otherwise the call results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in C:

```
char* foo(char *str)
{
  return str;
}
```

Or just:

```
void foo(char *str)
{
}
```

Since you aren't actually touching str.

If you want to understand C, and do your homework without help, go get yourself a copy of [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). Immediately!

Comment: Is that last declaration supposed to be `void foo...`?

Comment: yes, you caught me before I could fix it. or the whole thing could just be void foo() {} // :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, your function should allocate a string of the required size with `malloc`. For example, here's a function that repeats each character:

```
def repeat_each(char* s) {
  char* res = malloc(strlen(s) * 2 + 1);
  if (!res) return res;
  char* resp = res;
  while (*s) {
    *resp++ = *s;
    *resp++ = *s;
    s++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

It's the callers responsibility to `free` the returned string. Pay attention to not call `strlen` in a loop. If you need it more than once, store it in a temporary variable of type `size_t`.

Comment: And if the callee allocates the memory, who would tell the caller he has to deallocate it again?

Comment: @cli_hlt: in any case the one who doesn't read the specs is guilty :)

Comment: Can you use array notation to access your string or do you have to use pointer arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, it would be something like this:

```
void foo(char *str /* , int n */) {
    // do something
    // str[3] = 'c';
}
```

Remember that you can't exceed the allocated space for that string. Hence the optional int for specifying the length.

This is if you want to change the string but still keep it in its original storage.

If you want a new string based on the existing one, then:

```
char* foo(char *str /* , int n */) {
    char *ret = malloc(/* what you need */);
    // do something, probably copy str to ret
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is that you need a fundamental understanding of how strings are represented in C. Once you got that, the processing shouldn't be that difficult anymore.

I would suggest reading

http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/strings.htm

(the first url I could come up with that looks reasonable to me)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll check it out.

Comment: @Prydie np...it's not perfect, but if you have questions, don't hesitate to ask. In contrast to higher level languages (like Python) the most important thing is to realize that strings are just memory buffers of chars and that you have to handle all that memory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In C you probably need to also pass the maximum size you can use in the string.

```
char *fill_with_dots(char *data, size_t len) {
    char *dst = data;
    while (--len) *dst++ = '.';
    *dst = 0;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: you may not *need* to pass along the size of the string, but you should so that buffer overruns can be avoided.

Comment: @Obscure: it depends on the function. A function to delete, in-place, all of a character from a string, for instance, does not need a size: `char *deleteall(char *data, int ch);`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to understand what you ask as "manipulating" can mean a lot.

If you don't want to keep the original then you could define the function as following:

```
void changeString(char* str);
```

if you need to keep the original then you might want to copy the contents to a temporary buffer, change it and return it like this:

```
char* returnModified(char* str )
{
      char* tmp = malloc(strlen(str));
      strcpy(tmp, str);
      // do watever
      return tmp;
}
```

With the latest approach make sure you keep track of the allocated memory properly